# Kotlin MPP - build problems with Gradle on IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to build a multi module Gradle project with some Koltin MPP modules.

I have a very strange problem while trying to build a Kotlin MPP module. All of the specified dependencies are resolved, they can be seen from the Gradle configuration, but when I try to use some of the classes in the mobile targets (Android and iOS), I can't do it. The classes can't be resolved at all.

This is my gradle build file for the module in question:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}

group 'bg.dalexiev'
version '0.0.1'

def ktor_version = '1.3.1'
def serialization_version = '0.14.0'
def coroutines_version = '1.3.3'
def timber_version = '4.7.1'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionName '0.0.1'
        versionCode 1
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/androidMain/kotlin']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/androidMain/res']
        }

        test {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/kotlin']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

repositories {
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-jvm:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktor_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serialization_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"

    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timber_version"

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}

kotlin {
    android("android")

    def sdkName = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')
    def iosTarget = sdkName?.startsWith('iphoneos') ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64
    targetFromPreset(iosTarget, "ios") {
        binaries {
            framework()
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')

                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version"

                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serialization_version"

                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-common')
                implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
            }
        }

        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-native:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:$ktor_version"

                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serialization_version"

                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:$coroutines_version"
            }
        }

        iosTest {
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

configurations {
    compileClasspath
}
```

I was able to build a standalone gradle project with the same configuration without any problems. Any help and advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of the IDE? You should be on the latest for sure. I assume Kotlin is 1.3.61?

Comment: @KevinGalligan The Kotlin version is actually 1.3.70. I'm using IntelliJ Idea 2019.3.3 Community eddition.

Comment: I am pretty sure the native libraries you're listing aren't compatible with 1.3.70, so I don't see how the gradle build would work. For example, ktor 1.3.1 on native is for Kotlin 1.3.6x. Native builds are only compatible with the corresponding major Kotlin versions

Comment: @KevinGalligan You're right. I migrated to newer version on all mpp libraries and also recreated the faulty module and somehow it all clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your android dependencies are in the wrong block. Refactor your build.gradle to

```kotlin
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}

group 'bg.dalexiev'
version '0.0.1'

def ktor_version = '1.3.1'
def serialization_version = '0.14.0'
def coroutines_version = '1.3.3'
def timber_version = '4.7.1'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionName '0.0.1'
        versionCode 1
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/androidMain/kotlin']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/androidMain/res']
        }

        test {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/kotlin']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

repositories {
    google()
}

kotlin {
    android("android")

    def sdkName = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')
    def iosTarget = sdkName?.startsWith('iphoneos') ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64
    targetFromPreset(iosTarget, "ios") {
        binaries {
            framework()
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')

                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version"

                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serialization_version"

                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-common')
                implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
            }
        }

        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktor_version"
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-jvm:$ktor_version"
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:$ktor_version"
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktor_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serialization_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"
            implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timber_version"
        }

        androidTest.dependencies {
            implementation("junit:junit:4.12")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
        }

        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-native:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:$ktor_version"

                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serialization_version"

                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:$coroutines_version"
            }
        }

        iosTest {
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

configurations {
    compileClasspath
}
```